# How can I remove inventorydetail from Sales Order Line Item in Suitescript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

We allocation inventory detail at the sales order stage, committing stock as early as possible. If we close a line item or sales order, the quantity of stock remains on the item and associated inventory detail unless we void the whole order.

How do I automate the removal of the inventory detail of the single line?

I have tried reducing the quantity's to 0 on both the sales order line item and inventory detail, which raises errors on both counts. I have also tried removing the lines on the associated inventory detail which also raises an error.

I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For each line you close set the 'commitinventory'  to '3' for Do Not Commit.
not sure if that's a universal value for all Netsuite accounts but in one account I worked on the mapping was:

```
1 Commit Avail; 2 Commit Complete; 3 Do Not Commit
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can confirm the mapping is the same across Netsuite. Unfortunately that's not the issue, no stock is committed on the line, however there is still inventory detail attached to the line item. To remove this manually there is the x next to the box with the tick above when you select the line.